# From within a shell script I want to access input given from other command

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, input, output

I am messing around with shell scripts and I am trying to get my script to take input from another command, like say ls. It is called like this:

```
ls | ./example.sh
```

I try to access the input from within example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

but it echoes back nothing. Is there another way to reference parameters given to bash by other commands, because it works if I type in:

```
./example.sh poo
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters and input aren't the same thing:

```
$ ls
example.sh  foo
$
$ cat example.sh
for param; do
    printf 'argument 1: "%s"\n' "$param"
done

while IFS= read -t 1 -r input; do
    printf 'input line: "%s"\n' "$input"
done
$
$ ls | ./example.sh
input line: "example.sh"
input line: "foo"
$
$ ls | ./example.sh bar
argument 1: "bar"
input line: "example.sh"
input line: "foo"
$
$ ./example.sh $(ls)
argument 1: "example.sh"
argument 1: "foo"
```

Parameters are the arguments passed to the script to start it running, input is what the script reads while it's running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xargs to do that.

```
ls | xargs ./example.sh
```

Resource

https://ss64.com/bash/xargs.html

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/

Or read man page for it